# map that can take any basic type inside

Tags: c++, dictionary

I need to create a map that can contain as its value any basic data type such as double,float,string, char etc... to store values from a request for a server component.

I was thinking of using a map such as this: `std::map<std::string, void*>`, however I don't know that this is a very good solution.

I wondered if anyone can advice on a better solution.  The main point is that the values have to be in the same map.

Please advice?

Comment: Are the possible values constrained? Or can it be *absolutely any* type? What is this for? It's possible that there is a better solution if we know more of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[You could use `boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/any.html) as the value which can hold "any" type.

([It is better to use `boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant.html) if there are only finitely many "basic data types")

Answer (score 4):

Try [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/any.html) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant.html) for the members of the map.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a struct or union (which has an int field, float field, etc) be the value type for the map. This would be much clearer and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you basically need the same service as provided by Qt's `QVariant` type. I don't recommend hauling in Qt for just this one class, but you might want to look at the API and see if you want to create something like it.

Docs: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qvariant.html