# Storing a Map of template type arguments into a Vector in C++ : Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, vector, data-structures

I have a situation like, I need to implement "map" that takes any Object type arguments because, As of now I don't know which type of arguments I will store into the Map. Later I need to store that Map into a vector. 
I have written like :

```
 vector<Map>vect;
```

But the compiler says, I need to specify the argument types for the Map. Is there a way declaring as above?  If I need to implement Templates can anyone clearly say how to implement templates in map. I am very much new to C++.
In Java I can directly store map into a ArrayList, but in c++ it is very much complicated to me. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037346/map-that-can-take-any-basic-type-inside

Comment: Is `Map` something you have written or `std::map`  or something else? Is it a `Map<Object>`?

Comment: its a Map<object> taken from unordered_map header file

Comment: `std::vector<Map<object>>` in that case, though a "map" just having one type sounds odd to me. You'd expect a map to, erm, map from one thing to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know the type of object in map, you can use void* or unique_pointer.

```
std::vector<std::map<KeyType, void*>> vect;
```

Or if you actually mean that all values inherit from Object, then:

```
std::vector<std::map<KeyType, Object*>> vect;
```

As a side note, you never mention type of key, so perhaps you mean std::set instead of map?